# Django PostgreSQL : migrating database to a different directory

Tags: python, django, postgresql, amazon-ec2

I have a Django website running on an Amazon EC2 instance. I want to add an EBS. In order to do that, I need to change the location of my PGDATA directory if I understand well. The new PGDATA path should be something like /vol/mydir/blabla.

I absolutely need to keep the data safe (some kind of dump could be useful).

Do you have any clues on how I can do that ? I can't seem to find anything relevant on the internet.

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand why you need to move the pgdata directory, if you're creating a completely new EC2 instance.

Comment: I am sorry I should have been more clear. The website is already running on an EC2 Instance, I am just adding an EBS and therefore, should change the data location. Editing my original post accordingly.

Comment: You can use `pg_dumpall` to generate a complete dump of your postgres database.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks for your answers, I used :

find . -name "postgresql.conf" to find the configuration find, which was located into the "/etc/postgresql/9.3/main" folder. There is also pg_lsclusters if you want to show the directory data.

Then I edited that file putting the new path, restarted postgres and imported my old DB.